# Remove saved folder access info?

Tags: windows, windows-7, user-management

Yesterday we had a user who was having problems accessing a certain shared folder on our network.

When attempting to access the folder, I got the usual "Please enter your credentials here" dialog. Because that user's account has full permissions on a replication of all that data on another domain, and because I was being pressured by some higher-ups in the room, I typed in the credentials of another account I know has full access to that data on our local domain, told the computer to remember that login, and hit okay.

I'm content to leave things like that, but it has raised the question in my mind: "How do I delete that login/password data for access to those files from this PC?"

My google-fu seems pretty weak today, and I can't seem to think of the correct search terms to get the answer I want, so I'm asking you guys. How do I get rid of this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the credential manager in the control panel, Under users aand then Manage your credentials. You be able to see a list of realted login information. From here you can remove the login info to the shared resource.